# Can I join the Canadian Forces as a foreigner with a work visa?

Tags: working-visas, canada

I want to join the Canadian Army. I applied for a work visa and received an answer saying that :

> *Votre demande pour travailler au Canada a été approuvée. Un permis de travail vous sera délivré à votre arrivée au Canada*

Yet I read on Wikipedia that :

> **Canadian permanent residents are allowed to serve in the Canadian Forces** (CF) as long as the Chief of the Defence Staff (CDS) decides it would not prejudice the national interest. It is likely that a requirement of CF membership will be to aim to become a Canadian citizen within four years of enrollment (subject to Citizenship and Immigration Canada's (CIC) processing timeframes). Following changes to the Citizenship Act in 2015, there is also now a fast-track citizenship scheme available to current and past CF members, as well as certain prospective members (negating the requirement to become a permanent resident first in the latter case).
>
> [<sub>Wikipedia - List of militaries that recruit foreigners - 14/08/2018</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_militaries_that_recruit_foreigners)

I am not yet in Canada. Am I a permanent resident with a work visa ? Otherwise what else should I do ?

Comment: Froeigners are not allowed in the Canadian Armed forces. You need to apply to be a Permanent Resident. Go see an immigration consultant for information on that.

Answer (score 1):

You are a permanent resident if you land as an immigrant. Landed immigrants have an inherent right to work and do not get work permits.

Work permits are for temporary residents, so the text you have quoted concerning permanent residents does not apply to you, with the possible exception of the last clause.

Comment: Hmm okay, so what else should I do to become permanent resident ? Is _landing_ in Canada sufficient ?

Comment: @Marine1 No, it is not.  You need to be approved for immigration before you land or in some cases you can apply after you arrive as a temporary resident.  There are many different paths to permanent residence.  You can start by looking at the government's page [Understand permanent resident status](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/new-immigrants/pr-card/understand-pr-status.html).